# How can I Disable Mipmaps in Blender 3.4?

Tags: animation

How can I turn off mipmaps ? I searched this but I found nothing. Everyone says change lineer to closest but there is no option like this please help me.

Comment: This option can be found on any Image Texture node in shader nodes.

Comment: Where are you looking for this option?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I'm looking Material proporties and I already looked preferences.

Comment: @L0Lock I'm a new user I don't know where it is

Comment: It's in the object's material. Go to the *Shader Editor* and have a look at the node tree. There should be an *[Image Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html)* node. Set the *Linear* value to *Closest* - If this is not what you're looking for then edit your question and add a screenshot of what you have.